# XAMPP apache ports keep changing

Tags: apache, xampp, port

My apache ports keep changing on netstat of XAMPP control panel
like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ2FM.png) shows.

Note:
my localhost works fine, and httpd.exe is using 80, 443.
port changes per second.

Comment: Not sure if I had the same problem, but my php debugger "Xdebug" was on and the IDE was listening. Execution was stopped at a breakpoint the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. From my understanding this is normal.

I once found a post discussing it here: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=197896&sid=df3bb64d241e7e17c754fa1982a0fc4c

The main quote that put my mind at rest was:

> Apache listens for and accepts requests on ports 80 and 443 but it
>   does not service requests on those ports. When you or others connect
>   to your servers, they will be handled by other connections usually
>   using high ports. The control panel just looks for all ports
>   associated with a module. It is just picking up those client ports and
>   the box to show all the ports is just not big enough to show them all.

Comment: I am not sure about this. My colleagues didn't encounter this situation. so I think it's abnormal.

Comment: Do you all have Skype installed? I know that can interfere with standard ports

Comment: I changed Skype port before had my xampp installed.  So that won't be a problem , right?

Comment: No I don't think so, that's what I do. Really I think you are seeing default behaviour. XAMPP "Scans" other ports, mine does the same.

Comment: So, my xampp is scanning ports not changing it?

Comment: That's right, it's just scanning for connections. I'd appreciate the answer accept, if I've helped :)

Comment: @WinfredPeng Are you using XDebug? It happens to me when I am debugging ...

Answer (score -1):

The error that you're recieving is based on the fact that there's an error in your sql query. The XAMPP port changes when an SQL query fails to run. When this occurs the port changes; and your localhost becomes irresponsive due to the wrong port in the request.

Please double check your SQL command; to ensure there is no error in there.

I see this question everywhere on Google; it's not a problem with XAMPP. It's a problem with your SQL query.